# DataType Conversion Issue from DataTable to SelectItemList

Tags: html, data-conversion, selectlistitem

Here is my code. In which I'am trying to convert table into list. Data type of  *PatientAdmissionStatusId*  is **long** from table. Whats the right way to convert it or assign without conversion.

```
DataTable dtPatientAddmissionStatus = // Some Function returning dataTable
List<SelectListItem> list = dtPatientAddmissionStatus.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Field<long>("PatientAdmissionStatusId").ToString(),
                Text = x.Field<string>("PatientAdmissionStatusName").ToString()
            }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
```

also tried

```
    x.Field<string>("PatientAdmissionStatusId").ToString(),
    x.Field<long>("PatientAdmissionStatusId")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure DataType is long? try int

```
x.Field<long>("PatientAdmissionStatusId")
```